# detect when map has ended and imgs loaded jquery

Tags: jquery

```
 var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json, responseText, req) {
    if (typeof json.data != "undefined") {
        json.data.map(function(product) {
          markAvailable(product, lookRequestId);
        });
      } else {
        //console.log("successfull request but no products in array");
      } 
});



function markAvailable(product, lookRequestId) {
   $(".qv-overlay-container-" + lookRequestId + " [data-product-pid-thumb=" + product.id + "]").append('<img src='+product.image_groups[0].images[0].link+' />');
}
```

I loop through a list of products using data.map and call the function markAvailable for each one. Is there a way I can execute some code when this process has ended, when the loop of data.map has ended? Ideally I'd like to execute the code when all the images have loaded after appending.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for the images to load as well then try

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (json, responseText, req) {
        if (typeof json.data != "undefined") {
            var promises = json.data.map(function (product) {
                return markAvailable(product, lookRequestId);
            });
            $.when.apply($, promises).then(function () {
                //do your stuff here
            })
        } else {
            //console.log("successfull request but no products in array");
        }
    })
});

function markAvailable(product, lookRequestId) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var $img = $('<img src=' + product.image_groups[0].images[0].link + ' />').appendTo(".qv-overlay-container-" + lookRequestId + " [data-product-pid-thumb=" + product.id + "]");
    $img.on('load error', function () {
        deferred.resolve();
    })
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Comment: is there a way to check when all imgs have loaded too?

Answer (score 0):

You can check last item using:

```
json.data.map(function(product, idx) {
    if ( idx == json.data.length ){
       //your job here
    }
    markAvailable(product, lookRequestId);
});
```

Comment: is there a way to check when all imgs have loaded too?